# No named parameter with the name 'color' [Flutter] [Android Studio]

Tags: android

I get this error when running the project:No named parameter with the name 'color'
Here's the code:
[the color under label is underlined in red](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xsm9S.png)
What should I do to resolve this error?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you trying to pass your color to? Looks like you are trying to assign a color to the `ElevatedButton.icon` but it does not have color property.

Check [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ElevatedButton/ElevatedButton.icon.html) for properties in `ElevatedButton.icon`

Comment: Thanks, my issue is solved, but this code looks more complex to what this YouTuber is doing to change the color of his button:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ABmqtI7ec7E&list=PL4cUxeGkcC9jLYyp2Aoh6hcWuxFDX6PBJ&index=9

Comment: If you are trying to add change icon color, you should pass color to icons only. If you want to change the color of the button, pass it inside button style.